# Virtual domain variable in postfix/smtp_header_checks

Tags: postfix, regex

What Postfix virtual domain variable should I use in outgoing header creation?

## Current server

I'm running a database-driven virtual domain server managed by [PostfixAdmin](https://github.com/postfixadmin/postfixadmin).  I want to put statements in the header of all outgoing emails *using the Postfix system*, not using the responsible web app or client.

### We need to produce...

The question is ***not*** about a `List-Unsubscribe` header, which [we already know](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443003/using-list-unsubscribe-headers-in-emails-in-postfix-mail-sever) should look like...

**in the email header** :

```
List-Unsubscribe: mailto:unsubscribe@somedomain.tld
```

### How we produce...

We already know to achieve that [with a line](https://serverfault.com/questions/334036/postfix-how-to-apply-header-checks-only-for-specific-domains) tailored to [outgoing checks](https://serverfault.com/questions/510855/postfix-different-header-checks-for-incoming-and-outgoing-mail) `/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks`. So, if we have this line...

**main.cf** :

```
smtp_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks
```

(or some other setting like `some_setting = regexp:/etc/postfix/some_setting`?)

Then, we need in...

**/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks** :

```
/^Content-Type:/i PREPEND List-Unsubscribe: mailto:unsubscribe@somedomain.tld
```

But, that only works for a specific domain `somedomain.tld`; **I need a variable that depends on the sending domain.**

There are no `mydomain =`  settings anywhere in `main.cf` or any other `/etc/postfix/` files; all domains are managed by the virtual domain maps managed by MySQL.

So, this question is about ***vmail variables any sending header creation***, not only `List-Unsubscribe:`, as long as it works in creating `List-Unsubscribe:` from Postfix.

([Postfix docs](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydomain) aren't clear about usable vmail variables in headers.)

## Code with domain variable

This is my best solution: `$mydomain`.

**/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks** :

```
/^Content-Type:/i PREPEND List-Unsubscribe: mailto:unsubscribe@$mydomain
```

When sending from a virtual domain, is `$mydomain` the correct way to pass that domain into header or other email content creation sent by Postfix?

---

*(Using Postfix for this is important so that all emails will have this, even those sent from the simple CLI or by third party web apps using PHP via [MSMTP](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/msmtp), et cetera. We already know how to add it via server lang header.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Postfix` does not provide a built-in variable that directly corresponds to the sender's domain in `smtp_header_checks`, but we can use regex arguments from `header_checks` combined with `smtp_header_checks` to do the same thing.

First we use this custom header in

**/etc/postfix/header_checks** : add this

```
/^From:.*@(.*)/i PREPEND X-Sender-Domain:$1
```

Then prepend the `List-Unsubscribe` header using the custom `X-Sender-Domain` in

**/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks** : we have

```
/^X-Sender-Domain:(.*)/i PREPEND List-Unsubscribe: mailto:unsubscribe@$1
```

Then make sure in

**main.cf** : we have

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
smtp_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks
```

Then we reload with this command.

$ `sudo postfix reload`

Comment: Vanilla Postfix at its best!